# What type of tests would you run on this http GET request?

Tags: api-testing, rest

I'm writing up some postman tests for a REST API:

```
api/controller/getPerson?person=personID
```

I'm curious as to what types of things would come in your head for testing this? the call itself requires one paramater which is an int.  So far I've added

- Valid person, each key pair in the JSON response
- Response codes/Response times are accurate & respectable
- Negative ID
- ID greater than max int
- Symbols ID
- String ID
- Empty ID
- ID 0
- Double/decimal ID
- Response is returned in JSON

I'm looking to make a good quality set of tests to cover as much as possible and learn a thing or two at the same time, so what comes to mind for you when faced with a basic call like this?

Example Response would be:

```
   {
  "Balance": -1,
  "RoomNumber": "900",
  "DateOfBirth": 504939600000,
  "Deleted": false,
  "Forename": "Simon",
  "PersonNumber": "",
  "Address": "",
  "LanguageID": 2,
  "Password": "pa$$",
  "PeopleID": 60000,
  "Surname": "API",
  "Balance2": -1
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got some of the input checks.

Some thoughts:

- You mention Postman, so I'm guessing no DB access?
- The API returns the plaintext password?  That seems bonkers
- beyond the input checks you've listed, I might try an ID I know that exists vs. an ID I know doesn't exist
- some response checks beyond just a JSON validation would make sense

  - is the DateOfBirth reasonable?  Looks like a linux epoch time in ms?
  - are the LanguageID values valid?  Guessing that's an ENUM on the server/DB side, so you should be able to figure out what valid values are.  Same thing with the RoomNumber.
  - Unclear if Balance and Balance2 should be linked or can be cross-checked?
  - Verify that Deleted is a boolean

If you do have DB access, cross checking the API results vs. a SQL query would make a lot of sense.